# gnuplot scatter plot, labels with color

Tags: gnuplot, scatter-plot

i have a file with 4 columns (x value), (y value), (label), (rgb color)

for example

```
1 43.3 JOHN 034143
2 11.6 BRIAN 987654
3 85.2 JOHN 034143
4 72.7 ALEX 765342
5 4.9 PETER 876897
6 42.7 ALEX 765342
```

i would like to plot each label on the corresponding position (x,y) with the corresponding color.

for example

```
have JOHN be printed at coordinate (1, 43.3) with rgb-color 034143
and have BRIAN be printed at coordinate (2, 11.6) with rgb-color 987654
and have JOHN be printed at coordinate (3, 85.2) with rgb-color 034143
and ...
```

to be sure, i would also like the labels to be printed vertically (rotated 90 deg) :-)

how may i achieve this?

(unfortunately and admittedly, im too dummy to extract/synthesize the exact answer from other similar questions or from the official documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your color values are decimal numbers (rather than hex):

```
$DATA << EOD
1 43.3 JOHN 034143
2 11.6 BRIAN 987654
3 85.2 JOHN 034143
4 72.7 ALEX 765342
5 4.9 PETER 876897
6 42.7 ALEX 765342
EOD
set border 3; set tics nomirror
set xrange [0:*]   

plot $DATA using 1:2:3:4 with labels textcolor rgb variable rotate by 90
```

[image]

Comment: thx a million ethan. somehow on my system (mac os) i dont get any coloring. so i must be missing some trivial thing...

Comment: to ethans code, i applied '''(hex2rgbvalue(stringcolumn(4)))''' to the color column and got the expected result, see code for hex2rgbvalue here:  http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2012/08/converting-from-hex-string-color-to-its.html and i ALSO prepended "#" to the color entries (not enuff by itself though)

Comment: You can do it a little easier with `(int("0x".strcol(4))) ` for your original data.